# Initial seed access asset link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an initial seed that I am trying to add some html to the database. I would like to reference an image. But when I do this it does not contain the auto generated hash key.

Here is the code I have:

`<a href=\"><img src=\"/assets/Placeholder.png\"  alt=\"Add image 2\"></a>`

But I would like to use the actual production file.
If I was in a view i would use

`<%= image_tag "Placeholder.png" %>`

Is this possible in the initialseed file?

Comment: Can you please tell that what do you mean by auto generated hash key?

Comment: Are you saying you would like to seed your db with an image(s) file?

Answer (score 0):

If you [pre-compile assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) in production, it should generate a `manifest.yml` file with the respective fingerprint/hash for the file in question. You could do that and then use that hash in your seed, I believe.